# retrieving record of two rows from a database that dont give chat of a all users but only selected ones

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

```
Table 1 = thread ( thread_id , date_time )
Table 2 = subscribers ( subscribers(P_K) , subscribers_id , thread_id )
```

I am applying this query

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.thread_id, b.subscriber_id AS Subscribers, c.subscriber_id AS Subscribers 
FROM thread t 
LEFT OUTER JOIN subscribers b ON b.thread_id = t.thread_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN subscribers c ON c.thread_id = t.thread_id 
WHERE b.subscriber_id = 1 AND c.subscriber_id = 2;
```

It is giving me result:

```
thread_id    Subscribers    Subscribers 
1                1             2 
2                1             2
```

But i want only chat of two subscribers it is also giving me the chat of those two subscribers in which they have also chatted with another subscriber which is number 3 in a group chat . Please tell me the solution.

Comment: Can you include a sample dataset and the expected result?

Answer (score 0):

Use 2 not exists subqueries to eliminate those threads, that have participants other than 1 or 2

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.thread_id, b.subscriber_id AS Subscribers, c.subscriber_id AS Subscribers 
FROM thread t 
LEFT OUTER JOIN subscribers b ON b.thread_id = t.thread_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN subscribers c ON c.thread_id = t.thread_id 
WHERE b.subscriber_id = 1 AND c.subscriber_id = 2
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM subscribers e WHERE e.thread_id=b.thread_id AND e.subscriber_id NOT IN(1,2))
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM subscribers f WHERE f.thread_id=c.thread_id AND f.subscriber_id NOT IN(1,2));
```

Since you want matching threads only, you can change the join to inner join as well, depending on other needs.